# Is there any publicly available dataset of the student behaviors in massive online courses like Coursera?

Tags: data-request, education, internet

I need dataset of the *student behavior* in the massive online courses. By searching the internet, most of data I find about online courses is just the course information. But what I want is the *student behavior* data like how they take the video lecture, what are their grades, what is their behavior in the course forum, etc.. Is there any publicly available dataset on this kind of things?